# How to get a list of facebook users that also use my app with Laravel socialite?

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Like the title says, I have currently implemented a socialite login on my website but I don't know exactly how to get a list of user friends that also use my app when a user logs in.

The socialite documentation states the following code example to change the "scope". I've read somewhere else that you are suppose to use this?

```
return Socialite::driver('github')
        ->scopes(['scope1', 'scope2'])->redirect();
```

Nowhere does it state in the [socialite github readme](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) what scope means in this case though. Is this simply a social media api thing? Hopefully somebody can help me out.

It also states that setting up a scope with override all existing scopes, what are the default ones to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet of code you've provided is indeed correct. By defining your scopes like that, the user get's an overview of the permissions you require. They see this when loggin in to your application via Facebook.

To answer your main question: I don't think Facebook allows you to get a full list of people who use your app. (At least not with their names)

If you just need a number, you should read the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/insights/).

I'm not entirely sure about this, so please correct me if I'm wrong.